# How to keep size of images same which have different proportions?

Tags: html, css

I have product page, with 4 bootstrap columns. I am adding products through CMS editor. Below is HTML structure of single product. Now, Images of products have different proportions. So when I added them, they are displayed with different height and width. How to keep them in same size, in different size of screen.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p>
        <img src="PowerAbWheel.jpg" alt="PowerAbWheel.jpg" style="display:block;          margin: auto;">
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Power Ab Wheel<br></strong>
        <strong>Price:</strong> 
        <a href="# style="font-size: 20px;">$37.95</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is snapshot of page
[image]

Comment: what CMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the images are of same proportion. Limit all the images by `max-height` and `max-width`!

```css
.grid {display: block; overflow: hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.grid li {width: 32%; float: left; margin: 0.5%; height: 80px; display: block; background: #ccf;}
.grid li img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 75px; border: 1px solid #999; display: block; margin: 2px auto;}
```

```html
<h3>Same Proportions</h3>
<ul class="grid">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/175x75" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt=""></li>
</ul>
<h3>Different Proportions</h3>
<ul class="grid">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/175x750" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x320" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/750x100" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found solution, can you tell me how to align image in middle. Its now on top of paragraph. Here is link http://exrx.net/concrete5/store/older-adult-4

Comment: Use `line-height: 250px` for the image and `p` tag!

Comment: You need to remove `display: block` for your image and make it align inline. If that doesn't work, use `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle`!

Comment: I would mark it right, if have right solution. It looks like your solution is in UL LI. While my structure is in Bootstrap Grid. But i appreciate you tried to help me.

Comment: @user3288891 Should work buddy... It is the same logic... Plus you haven't posted the code when I answered I guess...